# Chrome extension - Copy data from popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple Chrome Extension that populates a Textarea in popup.html with some information retrieved from a website.

Now I'm just trying to copy information from that Textarea without luck.

I made this code in popup.js:

```
var copyEmailBtn = document.getElementById('copyButton');

copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert(copyEmailBtn);
  var emailLink = document.getElementById('copyButton');
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(emailLink);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
  // removeRange(range) when it is supported
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

I've added a button in popup.html with the following information:

```
<button id="copyButton">COPY</button>
```

In my manifest I have the following permissions:

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "clipboardWrite", "clipboardRead", "<all_urls>"]
```

It seems my click event is not being fired. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should check for errors and debug it in the correct devtools: the popup has its own devtools, which you can open by right-clicking inside the popup, then click "inspect" menu item. Your question doesn't contain a complete picture so I guess there's a trivial typo or the script is loaded in `<head>` but you don't use DOMContentLoaded listener or something like that. Also note, there's no need for all that getSelection and range stuff, you can simply do textAreaElement.focus(); textAreaElement.select(); document.execCommand('copy');

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo mistake from my side I didn't notice (I was searching in "common" console). It's possible to fire this event right after the "popup.html" opens instead of clicking a button?

Comment: Yes, just put the code at the start of popup script: it'll run each time the popup is shown.